# Google charts live update ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database, google-visualization

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a live update function to Google charts? I do not want to use a button to update the data; instead I would like graph to automatically change when the database data has changed. This is the code that I am using to show the line chart and it works correct.

index.php

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  var options = {
      width: '100%',
      height: 500,
      legend: 'none',
      colors: ['orange','red','green'],
      vAxis: {textStyle: {color: 'white'}},
      hAxis: {textStyle: {color: 'white'}}
    };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

getData.php
I get the data from my database in the following format:

```
$db_conn_pyr = connect();

function getOrderrader($datum){
 // gets order rows ...
}

$pastDate = date('Ymd', strtotime("-1 month"));

$sqlTrans = "SELECT DISTINCT D3611 FROM PUPROTRA WHERE D3625 = 'U' AND D3601 = 'O' AND
D3611 >= $pastDate ORDER BY D3611 ASC";

$resultTrans = odbc_exec($db_conn_pyr, $sqlTrans)or die(odbc_errormsg());

$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'datum', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Target', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Target', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Orderrader', 'type' => 'number')
    )
);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($resultTrans)){
$datum = utf8_encode($row['D3611']);
$ordernr = getOrderrader($datum);


$data['rows'][] = array(
    'c' => array(
        array('v' => $datum),
            array('v' => 240),
            array('v' => 160),
            array('v' => $ordernr)
        )
);
}

$string = json_encode($data);
echo $string;
```

many thanks
Linda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a javascript timer to recall your graph creation function after xxx seconds and it should work for you.